# Не получается найти все несуществующие ключи в массиве

Tags: php

Написал алгоритм, который, по идее, должен находить все несуществующие ключи в массиве. Есть исходный массив ключей, который я изъял из массива при помощи `array_keys()`

```
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 12
)
```

Есть массив, который я обхожу с помощью foreach и проверяю, есть ли в нём ключ, который находится в массиве ключей:

```
foreach($data['posts'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $cache_keys)) {
        array_push($nonexistent_keys, $key);
    }
}
```

После чего я вывожу в `error_log()` получившийся массив отсутствующих ключей и вижу это:

```
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 12
)
```

Это что получается, ключи 5, 6 и 7 он видит, а остальные нет? У меня только одно подозрение - foreach почему-то вместо `$key` отправляет мне номер итерации, а не номер самого индекса. Но почему?

Comment: используйте $value вместо $key. Просто посмотрите на листинг первого массива в вопросе, какие там ключи и какие значения

Comment: Попробуйте in_array вместо array_key_exists

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$data = [
    1 => 'One',
    2 => 'Two',
    3 => 'Three',
];
$cacheKeys = [1, 3];

$missed = array_diff(array_keys($data), $cacheKeys);

var_dump($missed); // [2]
```